# Disputed flags (despite closing question) and flags that are not counted.

Tags: support, bug, flagging

I do not understand why some of the flags that I raise, get eventually disputed although the question gets closed or why they do not appear at all in my flags counter. Specifically I have two questions when raising a flag in a question:

1. If I choose flag > it should be closed for another reason > ...,  then I do not get this credited as a helpful flag (in the case of course that the question gets eventually closed). In fact it does not appear at all in my raised flags-counter. It is as if I did not raise the flag at all.
2. But if instead of choosing that, I choose flag > it is very low quality, then if the question gets closed for example because it is off-topic, my flag counts as disputed.

What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Since you have the [3K privilege](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), it actually *is* the case that you never raised the close-flag at all, because once you gain this privilege all "close-flags" are transformed into close *votes*.
2. A low-quality flag is disputed as soon as *someone* is the low quality review queue disagrees with your assessment, or even if the post is edited. This is because low quality flags are meant for posts which are **unsalvagable**. Not simply *wrong*, but so completely incoherent that there's no sense to them. An example would be:

   > svhlny xuet
   >   kmh moxp sfq
   >   sqazdlpkzy
   >   kcgc cpf bkl
   >   snvsjxuqva
   >   coth nzzklb
   >   bbes ddhsdj
   >   kunzicqgtg
   >   vhp eeneoes.

   (See a previous discussion of this [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15224/8348).)

Comment: One could also consider [flagging cat-on-keyboard posts as spam](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234032/why-dont-we-treat-rubbish-the-same-as-spam/234035#234035), but a VLQ flag [also seems to be appropriate](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17233/will-implicit-down-vote-affect-my-reputation/17234#comment63818_17234) of course.

Comment: Shame. I was hoping the gibberish was actually a ROT13 encryption of something silly and amusing. -1 for not doing that, +1 for the information.

Comment: @DanielR No, one must not flag them as "spam," and the link does not say you can do this. It says you could flag as "offensive, abusive or hate speech."

Comment: ... which us somewhat un-intuitive, but the flag description backed it up: "contains content that a reasonable person would deem inappropriate for respectful discourse." It's pretty clear that "svhlny xuet kmh moxp..." does not fit anyone's idea of respectful discourse.

Comment: @quid Ah, thanks for the correction. I guess it was unintuitive enough for me to remember it wrong.  And I agree the flag description backs it up well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link!