# A post I flagged was declined but then closed for the same reason of the flag

Tags: support, flagging, specific-flag

I flagged https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074123/is-g-commutative for being off topic but the flag was declined. However, the post was closed for the **exact** same reason I flagged it. Why would the flag be declined then?

[image]

[image]

---

I did read [Disputed flags (despite closing question) and flags that are not counted.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18782/disputed-flags-despite-closing-question-and-flags-that-are-not-counted) so I understand why a low quality flag would be declined since it goes to the user queue. Does this flag go to some queue as well?

Comment: You expect total consistency out of our body of voters?! :)

Comment: @rschwieb I didn't know if those flags went to a queue so when I asked the question I wasn't sure if it was mod or voter action.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you flagged the question for closure it was placed in the close votes queue. Here it received [three reviews](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/322644), and each of these users opted to leave the question open. It is because of this that your flag was marked as declined.

As for the eventual closure of the question, three of the close votes happened before your flag, and two after the review had concluded.

(In summary, the fate of close-flags can depend on the lottery of users involved in reviewing them.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't sure that flag went to a queue or to a mod.

Comment: @dustin: The only user flags that really go to the moderators now are comment flags and mod-only "other" flags. Low quality and not an answer flags are visible to moderators, but we generally let the reviews handle them and instead handle the frequent "disputed low quality review" flags that follow. Spam/offensive flags are also visible to moderators, but in a perfect world six regular users would remove most of these posts without moderator intervention. (Admittedly, we don't live in a perfect world.) Close-flags go directly to reviews and don't even show up in the moderator flag centre.